# Replacing characters in a list based on conditions

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to replace the characters in my list based on some conditions.

```
tmp = ['T', 'h', 'e', '/', ' * ', 's', 'k', 'y', ' * ', 'i', 's', '/', '/', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e']
tmp_string = "".join(tmp)
result = re.sub(r'[\*|/]{2}', ' ', tmp_string)
result = result.title().replace('*', ' ').replace('/', ' ').replace('  ', ' ')
```

There is a slight change I want to make to the code as it doesn't match my expected output.

- Expected:  The Sky is Blue
- My Output: The Sky Is Blue

I dont want the 'i' of 'is' to get capitalized.

Comment: What is `tmp` here?

Comment: You called `title()` which capitalizes the first letters of words. If you don't want that, don't call `title()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator with a ternary expression to check if the characters are alphanumeric or not:

```py
import re

l = ['T', 'h', 'e', '/', ' * ', 's', 'k', 'y', ' * ', 'i', 's', '/', '/', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e']

tmp = "".join(char if char.isalpha() else ' ' for char in l)

# This will put spaces where the * and / are

# then use regex to compress the spaces

mystr = re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', tmp)

print(mystr)
```

Outputs: The sky is blue

Then, to get your desired output:

```py
chars = []
not_capitalize = set(['is', 'and']) # you can put other words in here that you don't want to capitalize

# split will create an array of words split on spaces
for char in mystr.split():
    if char in not_capitalize:
        chars.append(char)
        continue

    # Separate the first letter from the rest of the word
    first_letter, rest = char[0], char[1:]

    # stitch the uppercase first_letter with the rest of the word together
    chars.append("%s%s"% (first_letter.upper(), rest))

# join and print
print(' '.join(chars))

# Gives The Sky is Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `title()` which will capitalize each first character of the string. IUCC a simple example will get you going. Use `title()` with condition

```
' '.join([i.title() if i not in ['is','and'] else i for i in 'the sky is blue'.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re
tmp=['T', 'h', 'e', '/', ' * ', 's', 'k', 'y', ' * ', 'i', 's', '/', '/', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e']

misc_words = ('is', 'the')

tmp_string = "".join(tmp)
result = re.sub(r'[\*|/]', ' ', tmp_string)
result = re.sub(r' +', ' ', result) # replace one or more consecutive spaces with a single space
#result = result.title().replace('*', ' ').replace('/', ' ').replace('  ', ' ') # this is done by fixng the first regex
words = result.split()
new_words = []
for word in words:
    if word not in misc_words:
        new_words.append(word[0].upper() + word[1:])
    else:
        new_words.append(word)

print(new_words)
```